# How can I use Elasticsearch to store and retrieve the system performance

Tags: c#, node.js, .net, elasticsearch

I want to store data of system performance Metrices like (Performance monitor in windows) for platform like  (Linux, Windows and Mac OS).
This capturing will happen in every 2 mins or 5 mins interval.
After capturing, this data would be displayed on dashboard with graphical representation chart.

How can I use Elasticsearch to store and retrieve the system performance monitor without using any other database?

Answer (score 0):

You need a so called [ELK](https://www.elastic.co/elastic-stack/) (Elastic Stack)

Short sum:

On your server (or use the cloud of Elastic) install:

- `Elasticsearch` Place where the data lives
- `Kibana` Visualisation

At your enviroment:

- `Beats` Install the matching beat shipper at every system you want to collect metrics
- `Logstash` Install it on every system wehre you want to collect logs

Comment: Logstash doesn't have to be installed everywhere, it's not recommended actually.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Andreas . I'am very beginner in this kindly let me know any link from where I can install Beats and Logstash also I don't want to use any database for storing purpose. thanks

Comment: I suggest you to use the [free trail](https://cloud.elastic.co/registration?elektra=en-elastic-stack-page) which gives you elasticsearch and kibana in the cloud. In there you can follow then the `add Data` examples to set uf Beats on your system. It gives you then a very good idea how all works together.

Comment: Thank you so much @Andreas for the help I will try this.